# How do I use CSS and JS files within a HTML file being sent with Express?

Tags: css, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('main.html', { root : __dirname})
});

app.listen(9000, function(){
console.log('Listening on port 9000');
});
```

This current block of code works fine. Express is required and assigned to the variable app.

A HTML file is then sent (from the same directory) using res.sendFile as part of the app.get method.

Within the HTML file I am referencing a css file in the same directory, yet nothing is happening.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mainstyle.css'>
```

How am I able to send the CSS file to the browser for use? res.sendFile does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a static files directory. Create a folder called public and then include this line:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Don't include public in the file path when you include the css file though. All of your static files can go in that folder. Or, better still, create sub-folders for styles, images, fonts etc.

You can read more about it here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

I think the problem you're having is that you're trying to create a web application from scratch using Express without any of the surrounding functionality. Your app sends a file when you navigate to the URL. It does not listen for specific requests for files and respond to them, it does not handle missing files, server errors etc.

You could do all that from scratch but in fact Express have created an application generator which creates a skeleton app for you with the web server, public folder, routes etc. It's called Express Generator and you can find it here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

That's a brilliant starting point for an MVC application. You get the package.json file for additional node modules, a template engine called Jade (although I prefer Hogan) for dynamic content and once it's created your app, you can fire it up by typing "npm start" in a console window.

Comment: I'll assume that I'm placing my CSS file in the public folder?

Comment: my file structure is:

Comment: public
> mainstyle.css
main.html
app.js

Don't suppose anything is wrong?

Comment: That didn't come out right. Anyway, are you sure there is not something I'm missing?

Comment: The answer is quite long so I'm going to try and put it in to my original answer. Bear with me a minute or 2.

Comment: I'll use this to understand what I'm missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if(req.url == "/" || req.url == "/main.html"){
res.sendFile('/main.html', { root : __dirname})
}else if(req.url == "/mainstyle.css"){
res.sendFile('mainstyle.css', { root : __dirname})
}
});

app.listen(9000, function(){
console.log('Listening on port 9000');
});
```

Comment: I hate to say this didn't do my any favours either. Thank you though.

Comment: i'm sorry it should be start with slash (/) `/main.html` not `main.html` i updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now aware of what was going wrong.

From the instance I started, I was experimenting with different code. The browser than created cache based on the incorrect code my server was providing, so no matter what I changed, the browser was reffering to it's cache to load, in this case, erroneous code.

For everyone who may be experiancing with similar issues when entering the correct code, clear cache history or use a incognito/private browser for developing.